# json query using onkeyup handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My goal for my code is to execute a json query request using a textfield to designate the location
it is a quick search based text searching a specific website that is different from the location

eg:
if i type in www.calsolum/abc i want it to search the website calsolum for 3 json files:

'a', 'ab', 'abc' the last one being the actual json file

my index file looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="location" onkeyup="myFunction()">
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

the script.js looks like this

```
var myFunction = function(event) {

var payload = {location: $(this).val()};

var jqxhr = $.getJSON('/location', payload);

jqxhr.done(function(data) {
   console.log(data); 
});
};

// jQuery on DOM ready
$(function() {
  $("#location").keyup(myFunction);
});
```

So far it seems as though i get the right requests made but going from the errors the program is looking in the wrong location
Any help would be greatly appreciated. If any clarification is required do not hesitate to ask.

EDIT2: so i've implemented the edits suggested and my new error when running it is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

and

```
 GET http://mobile.sheridanc.on.ca/location?location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sightlineinnovation.com%2Fsyst35288%2FAPI%2Fv1.0%2Fexchanges%2FWSA 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Well, you're declaring a variable `x` inside a function. It's a local variable, so it's not available outside the function.

Comment: You want to do a getJSON request for each keystroke ?

Comment: You should either define var x outside the function or return it. That's a local variable and it's scope is the function. So basically you're function storing some data in a variable which won't be accessible afterwards. Plus your html tags are messed up. You have script and input between head and body.

Comment: okay so with everyone's suggestions i moved the JSON requestion to inside the function but theres an Illegal invocation error and ive no idea what that means.
and to clarify i'd like the request for each keystroke but i also want it to append the previous keystrokes

eg: for if i type car i want it to make 3 requests: c, ca, car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you

```
var myFunction = function(event) {

    var payload = {query: $(this).val()};

    var jqxhr = $.getJSON('/path/to/location_query', payload);

    jqxhr.done(function(data) {
       console.log(data); 
    });
};

// jQuery on DOM ready
$(function() {
  $("#location").keyup(myFunction);
});
```

Each time a user types something in the `<input>`, this will make a `getJSON` request with the following payload `{query: X}` where `X` is the value of the input.

Comment: Look like he want to do quick search based text rather than sent out which key end user pressed. I think his question is not quite clear.

Comment: ok i've tried the code exactly as youve written but i get 2 errors
First is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
Second is: GET http://mobile.sheridanc.on.ca/location?location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sightlineinnovation.com%2Fsyst35288%2FAPI%2Fv1.0%2Fexchanges%2FWSA 404 (Not Found) 
my json file is stored on different website so i think that complicates things because it seems to be looking for the file on the local website

Comment: @Calsolum, if you wrote code exactly as I did, you wouldn't see a `toLowerCase` error; nowhere in my code does that function exists. Second, `/location` is just an example path; you have to use a request path that matches one your server is using to process your request and return JSON. I made an edit that should make this a little more clear.

Comment: @TelvinNguyen, yeah I had that as the second part of my answer. I updated it to make things a little more clear thoguh.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was a mistake on my end as you pointed out and it now works as need it to

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend binding the event via jQuery like so, so you have a standard way of getting the event data:

```
$("#location").on("keyup", myFunction);
```

Also, doing this, you must get rid of the onkeyup="myFunction()" on the input element.

Change your myFunction function to accept an argument:

```
function myFunction(event) { .... }
```

Then, you can check which key code is pressed by checking:

```
var keyCode = event.which; // example usage, returns a number indicating the keycode
```

Hopefully, this helps you get closer to what you need

For the JSON - you need to call $.getJSON *inside* the event handler, putting it out side of myFunction() will only run run once outside of the event.  You may want it to run every time the event triggers.

Answer (score 1):

From your example it looks like the variable 'x' is closed in the function 'myFunction', you might want to move the variable into the function body ie:

```
function myFunction(){
    var x=document.getElementById("location");

    //Moved getJSON inside 'myFunction' and added 'x' as second JSON param
    $.getJSON('location', x, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction(){
    $.getJSON('location', {mylocation: $('#location').val()}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Each time user type one word, it makes a request such as

```
[your_server]/location?mylocation=[what user typed on location field]
```

And then on your server, just get "mylocation" as querystring.